# How to map HTML form data to Django model

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have a (quite complex) HTML form full of logic that triggers based on different choices in the `selectpickers` with fields that don't have quite the same names as the corresponding fields in the Django model, and sometimes I fear that I will need to add some logic when it comes to going from the data sent from the HTML form and to the Django model. I realise that I can probably not use a `ModelForm` in Django to handle this and have been looking for some examples of using the standard `django.forms.Form` to map the HTML form into my model but I haven't really found much. Can someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your html form already exists and somehow you want to read in the POST data from that form.  Without making any further assumptions as to how you ended up with an html form without a django ModelForm or forms.Form output via a view - as long as the form action location is mapped via a route to a view - the view can then process the request.POST data.  Again all form validation goodness of django is out the door if you did not use django forms (model or forms based) and you have to do your own validations in the view then.  Once the form data has been validated, initialize your model object like this: my_obj = ModelName(field_name1=form_input_data1, field_name2=form_input_data2, ...) and that's it.  Then you can do my_obj.save().

Now let's say, it's not so bad.  You actually are using the forms.Form inheritance to create your django-istic form class which has no direct relationship with the model.  Now you can use the form related validation clean_field and clean steps etc... as well as all the built-in field types internal validation django automatically does.  Then when you read in the POST data - do whatever it takes to map the form fields (via any transformation as necessary) to the django model object you are trying to construct, keeping in mind the default values and any model save custom assignments that may happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can not just map a html form into your django model. You need to create a model form first and then render it in html.

If you want to somehow map your html form to model. First render your ModelForm in html. Create the exact copy of the html format of your django form and use it in html. Catch that in your view and process it like model form. But anyway you have to create the ModelForm.